# AxiosInstance setting default type to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" instead of expected "multipart/form-data"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

axios and axiosInstance behave differently when we exclude the Content-Type from header and send image. axios defaults to "multipart/form-data" as expected but axiosinstance goes for "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

I want to send image from axios to backend. The Content-Type should be something like
[image]

The Content-Type is multipart/form-data + boundary calculated dynamically. My backend works fine when uploaded from postman. Setting Content-Type to only 'multipart/form-data' (without mentioning boundary) or adding custom boundaries doesn't seem to work.

On some research i learnt that axios will automatically set boundaries if we exclude the Content-Type from header. It seems to be true with axios but not with axiosInstance.

Please refer to the screenshots below

I have setup an axiosInstance which has interceptors attached to manage JWT authentication tokens.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { BACKEND_URL } from './config';
import { store } from './redux/store';
import { setLoginFalse } from './redux';

const baseURL = BACKEND_URL;

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: baseURL,
  timeout: 360000,
  transformRequest: [
    function (data, headers) {
      const accessToken = window.localStorage.getItem('access_token');
      if (accessToken) {
        headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;
      } else {
        delete headers.Authorization;
      }

      return JSON.stringify(data);
    },
  ],
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    accept: 'application/json',
  },
});

// handling the expiry of access tokens through response interceptors

axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
    // code for managing JWT tokens
);
export default axiosInstance;
```

First i will send it using axios (not axiosInstance the i just defined)

```
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('profile_pic', file, file.name);

    axios
      .put('/users/profile-pic-upload/', formData)
      .then((res) => console.log(res))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

I am printing the Content-Tyoe in server side. We can see that it set the type correctly.

[!Server side printing Content-Type for axios][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zvjl2.png)

But when i use axiosInstance for same (i don't specify Content-Type in both cases and let axios pick it).

```
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('profile_pic', file, file.name);

    axiosInstance
      .put('/users/profile-pic-upload/', formData)
      .then((res) => console.log(res))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

In this case axiosInstance picked "www-form-urlencoded" differeing from axios which picked "multipart/fform-data" with correct boundaries.

[image]

I cannot set Content-Type: "multipart/form-data" it won't work without boundary. Also copying the same boundary as sent by Postman (for same image) from axios doesn't seem to work.

I somehow need to tell axiosInstance to default to 'multipart/form-data' without setting the Content-Type (becuase boundaries need to be calculated dynamically)

I have to use axiosInstance, i cannot use fetch or just axios because i have an interceptor bound to axiosInstance which handles refresh tokens.

Please suggest any fix for this.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: did you try to not set the headers in your axiosInstance, to let the browser do it ?

Comment: Yes doing so will set the header to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" for axiosInstance. But it sets "multipart/form-data" correctly for axios. Also i noticed that if i omit the Content-Type it doesn't care about the incoming content and sets "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" for everything (even JSON data)