# Possible bug with axios default headers and transformRequest

Tags: reactjs, axios

This bug has caused serious trouble for me. Finally i was able to get to the root of it.

(A similar version of bug has been reported in GitHub but it has been marked as fixed)

Axios will fail to set the correct header type and goes for default header type when transformRequest is used.

I am not sure what exactly is causing this issue but here is a quick way of reproducing the issue.

Here i have defined an axiosInstance

```
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: baseURL,
  timeout: 360000,

  transformRequest: [
    function (data, headers) {
      const accessToken = window.localStorage.getItem('access_token');
      if (accessToken) {
        headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;
      } else {
        delete headers.Authorization;
      }
      return JSON.stringify(data);
    },
  ],
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    accept: 'application/json',
    Authorization: `Bearer ${window.localStorage.getItem('access_token')}`,
  },
});
```

Now i have to send multipart/form-data.

```
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('profile_pic', file, file.name);

    axiosInstance
      .put('http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/profile-pic-upload/', formData)
      .then((res) => console.log(res))
      .catch((err) => alert(err));
```

Since formData is contains image here i expected the axios to override the default header's content-type from 'application/json' to 'multipart/form-data'. But it turns out the content-type in the sent request packet is still 'application/json'.

But when i comment out the transformRequest section. Surprisingly it correctly sets the content-type to 'multipart/form-data'.

```
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: baseURL,
  timeout: 360000,

  transformRequest: [
    // function (data, headers) {
    //   const accessToken = window.localStorage.getItem('access_token');
    //   if (accessToken) {
    //     headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;
    //   } else {
    //     delete headers.Authorization;
    //   }
    //   return JSON.stringify(data);
    // },
  ],
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    accept: 'application/json',
    Authorization: `Bearer ${window.localStorage.getItem('access_token')}`,
  },
});
```

I am using axios 0.20 (i noted that axios 0.21 also has same issue as well).

I found a similar issue  on Github it says it has been fixed in axios 0.20
https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/2623

Please confirm that whether this is an existing bug or am i doing something wrong.

I have written more detailed description in my previous stackoverflow post.

[AxiosInstance setting default type to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" instead of expected "multipart/form-data"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68140003/axiosinstance-setting-default-type-to-application-x-www-form-urlencoded-instea)